# how do i subtotal on groups based on a condition

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is grouped on `clinic`, `staffname` with subtotals by `clinic`. I need to count patients by staff where they had more than 1 admit date. I can get the correct grand total, but on the detail and subtotals, it is a progressive number.

Here's what I want

```
clinic1
staffname1   10
staffname2   95
subtotal    105
clinic2
staffname3    6
subtotal      6
grand total 111
```

Here is what I get:

```
clinic1
staffname1   10
staffname2  105
subtotal    105
clinic2
staffname3  111
subtotal    111
grand total 111
```

Comment: what data you have in detail section? and what data you kept in staff group?

Comment: I have headings in staff group header. These are hidden for drilldown. On group footer for Staffname i have staffname, several other totals and a formula to count visits > 1. I have nothing in detail because this is a summary page with drilldown.

Comment: I would suggest you to place the fields in detail and take summary for staff and clinic then u get correct results and finally supress details

Comment: I copied my fields to detail. In my gf3 (grouping in patientid) i have a column that shows the distinct count of visits. I want to count any that are greater than 1, but i cant reference that count anywhere because it is a running total field. Any ideS about how to code to count those > 1?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this may depend on the structure of your data, e.g., what is in your "detail" level. I am also assuming that you want to count of how many patients had more than one admit date, *not* the total number of admits for patients with multiple admits. Given that, and assuming a patient will only appear once per admit date, then this should work:

1. Group by patient also, so it's clinic -> staff -> patient, but suppress that group.
2. Create a formula to count if the number of records in each patient group is more than 1, something like this: `if count({patient},{patient}) > 1 then 1 else 0`
3. Take the formula you just created, and use it to make a summary field wherever you want a total, e.g., in the staff head it will give you a count or that staff member, in clinic it will do so for clinic, etc.

Something else to consider: I'm guessing this could be intended to gauge staff on their quality by seeing how many patients had to seek additional treatment. Even if that's not the full intent, whatever this is being used for could be skewed by staff encountering more/fewer patients. For example, staff that have 10 readmits out of 100 visits would look worse than someone who only had 5 readmits, but had also only seen 20 patients.

So: Along with the metric on which you are requesting information, I would also add a ratio metric. In the staff header, this would be straightforward: `count({patients}) / distinctcount({patients})` which will give you the ratio of distinct to repeat visits. Keep in mind also that this could skew high for a staff member that had, for example, 50 patients, but one of them came back a dozen times.

Comment: Thank you for feedback and extra food for thought. What you said about skewing is so true, but those values are also in the report. I tried to address both comments in my reply to Siva.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of the fields that has `Greater than 1`.

`Assuming the count field is a database field and value coming directly from database`

1. Create a formula `@Count` and write below code. Place the forumla in details.
   :

   ```
   if(databaswefield.count > 1)
   then 1
   else 0
   ```
2. Now take the summary of the `@count` formula in required group footers.

Let me know if you are looking for something different.

Edit..............................................................

If I got your comment correctly.

Though you take `distinct count` you can use that in your calculations by storing the value in a `shared variable`. Something like below and you can retrive value from that variable

```
Shared Numbervar count;
count:=distinctcount(patientid)
```

Comment: I do not have the count in a table. I am using 2 views. One for outpatient and one for inpatient. I have to do a distinct count on inpatient visits and this seems to keep me from using it in summaries.